# Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, random, rows

I have a dataframe df having two columns 'voltage'(v) and 'current'(I). I want to randomly select 5 values of 'voltage' from the file, save it in 1D array like [v1,v2,v3,v4,v5], and save the corresponding values of currents in another 1D array like [I1,I2,...,I5]. Here is what I tried:

```
 df=pd.read_csv(file,sep=",",header=None,usecols=[0,1],names=['voltage','current'])

#pick 5 random values of voltage and save it in np array
 V= np.array( df['voltage'].sample(n=5))
```

How to do the same with the corresponding values of I at selected values of V?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need:

```
arr = df.sample(n=5).values
a = arr[:, 0]
b = arr[:, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

While jezrael's answer does provide the desired output, the answer to your question would be:

```
V= df['voltage'].sample(n=5)
I = df.loc[V.index,'current']
```